# How do I find the Alexa traffic rank of a site that uses a subdomain?

Tags: alexa

I'd like to compare the traffic rank for some of the more popular sites in different categories.  If I [search Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/search?q=webmasters.stackexchange.com&r=site_siteinfo&p=bigtop) for `webmasters.stackexchange.com`, for example, the only result is all of Stack Exchange.  Similarly, if I try to search for `answers.yahoo.com` I get the results for all of Yahoo!.  How do you separate out a subdomain when searching for the traffic rank of a site?  I've tried manipulating the Alexa traffic stats URL with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to get a rank for a subdomain, Alexa groups subdomains together, the only stats visible by subdomain is the percentage of traffic

from [Stackexchange.com Site Info](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackexchange.com) on Alexa:

[image: Alexa Subdomain Stats]

So you can determine your own subdomain site rank based off % traffic

Comment: Thank you.  This gave me enough information to come up with a reasonable estimate.

Comment: Buddy your answer is wrong . Now subdomains are getting different alexa ranks, blogspot.com hosted domains like example : love.blogspot.in has different alexa rank and hubpages subdomain are also getting different alexa rank.